# How do I remove CompizConfig Settings Manager via the terminal?

Tags: compiz, command-line, uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I uninstall software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143/how-can-i-uninstall-software)

I've recently installed CCSM, and it was giving me a hard time. So all I'm asking is a terminal command line to remove it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could `sudo apt-get remove compizconfig-settings-manager`

Or if you want to remove the program and the downloaded package you could
 `sudo apt-get purge compizconfig-settings-manager`

If you are using **aptitude** (apt-get's big brother ^^) then do

`sudo aptitude remove compizconfig-settings-manager` to remove it or

`sudo aptitude purge compizconfig-settings-manager` to eliminate the program and the downloaded package.