# How do I uninstall Nixnote

Tags: uninstall

I downloaded and installed the 32-bit nixnote package from sourceforge. It was 1.4 version .deb package download, and when I clicked on it, software center opened, and I installed through software center. But when I tried to find it to uninstall, it is nowhere to be found in Software Center. I do I uninstall it then?

Comment: Check out this link : http://askubuntu.com/questions/1143/how-can-i-uninstall-software?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Open a terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get remove nixnote
```

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal and uninstall it with `sudo dpkg -r nixnote`

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and uninstall it with

```
sudo dpkg -r nixnote2
```

or

```
sudo apt-get remove nixnote2
```

because the package name has been changed.