# How can I uninstall Kdevelop from Ubuntu?

Tags: uninstall

I want to uninstall Kdevelop from Ubuntu.

It was not possible to create, debug and compile C programs, only C++.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install kdevelop`

Comment: @nickanor That is how to **install** it, not how **uninstall** it.

Comment: possible duplicated: [How can I uninstall software?](http://askubuntu.com/q/1143/62483)

Comment: @lucio oh crap, my bad.. here's another one, `sudo apt-get --purge remove kdevelop`

Answer (score 3):

To uninstall it just open a terminal and enter the next command:

```
sudo apt-get remove kdevelop
```

To also remove the configurations file of this software, enter the next command:

```
sudo apt-get purge kdevelop
```