# uninstall sqlyog in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql

I am new to ubuntu and have started using ubuntu since 3 weeks.I used sqlyog in windows.so I had installed sqlyog in ubuntu.now i want to delete sqlyog from my ubuntu system.please provide step by step process to uninstall sqlyog from my system.

Comment: Check the link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/1143/how-can-i-uninstall-software    and     http://askubuntu.com/questions/151941/how-can-you-completely-remove-a-package

Comment: @Harshini Did you install `SQLyog` using `Wine`?

Comment: yeah..i had followed this tutorial..http://www.andrewault.net/2008/12/24/sqlyog-on-ubuntu/