# I want to Remove Arduino IDE 1.8.3 "No Such File or Directory"

Tags: directory

I've looked over dozens of similar questions, nothing has jumped out as applicable. 
ls returns "arduino-1.8.3" {lower case}
ron@ron:~$ cd (or sudo cd) /arduino-1.8.3 returns No Such File or Directory"

In the directory is uninstall.sh but it won't run from the file manager.

I realize I'm probably missing something obvious to an experienced user which I'm not.

TIA

Ron

Comment: Thank you. While I still need to learn why I can't get into the directory, you did provide the answer to the immediate problem that I hadn't thought through..

Comment: If `ls` shows a directory `arduino-1.8.3` in the current directory, then you can enter it using `cd arduino-1.8.3` or `cd ./arduino-1.8.3` but **not** `cd /arduino-1.8.3` since that means a location in the `/` directory - not the current one.

Answer (score 1):

To uninstall arduino, either...

In `terminal`...

```
sudo apt-get purge arduino arduino-core
```

or

If the arduino folder is in your home folder...

In `terminal`...

```
cd ~/arduino-1.8.3 # use the exact folder name here
sudo ./uninstall.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

if i get your problem as like you want to remove arduino from your pc but cant,
probably your problem, not writing down the programme name fully, so pls learn the exact name by using;

```
dpkg -l |grep arduino
```

and pls go this links as told before;

[How can I uninstall software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143/how-can-i-uninstall-software)