# How to completely remove GlassFish and reinstall it

Tags: uninstall, webserver, netbeans, glassfish

I installed NetBeans 8.2 with GlassFish 4.1.1, but something didn't work, so I install it again with instructions from some website, and it worked perfect till now. Maybe I deleted something when I cleaned the computer memory. Don't know what is the problem, I'm new with this, never worked with servers and web applications before.

Anyway, I want to completely uninstall it with all files and then install again fresh, clean, working one.

How to do that using Terminal? I have Ubuntu 18.04, and want GlassFish 4.1.1.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1144/489056 Or : `sudo apt-get remove <application_name>`

Comment: What command did you use to install it `sudo apt install` or `sudo dpkg -i <app_name>`?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen When I finished installing JDK 8 using `sudo apt install`, I downloaded zip file `http://download.java.net/glassfish/4.1/release/glassfish-4.1.zip` and then followed some instructions, I don't know

Comment: Can you provide the link to those instructions?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen that was long ago, but should be this one https://idroot.net/linux/install-glassfish-ubuntu-16-04/

Comment: If is that link then it's simple just go to the root of your server and delete the Glassfish file found there!

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with GlassFish. Was it installed from a .deb or from apt?
If so, then follow this
Verify the package is installed first. Something like.

```
sudo dpkg --list | grep -i glass
```

If you see it listed as installed, something like.

```
ii  <package name>
```

Then uninstall.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge <package name>
```

Answer yes if prompted.

If not, that means it was manually installed.
I see some reference to uninstall it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2427/gjxfv.html#gkrfi)

Looking around, some older posts suggested removing `/opt/glassfishx`, where x is the version number. So in your case.

```
rm -rvf /opt/glassfish4
```

Might be the answer after successfully killing the service.