# Ubuntu Software no longer works on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-center, 20.04

I have just upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04.
Before the upgrade, the updater informed me that it would no longer support Ubuntu Software.
After the upgrade is successful, I found that I can't open Ubuntu Software, but when I go to terminal and type `gnome-software`, I can use Ubuntu Software.

I also checked all the apps. I found that there are 2 Ubuntu Softwares in my system. One is named "*Ubuntu Software*", which doesn't work at all and the other is named only "*Software*"

[image]

How can I fix this issue? How can I delete *Ubuntu Software* completely? Or is there another way to cope with this?

Answer (score 0):

The pre-installed store application is a [snap application](https://snapcraft.io/docs/getting-started). It can be removed by using the following command in Terminal

```
snap remove snap-store
```

The other seems to be the (GNOME) Software (package name: `gnome-software`) application [installed via `apt`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1144/480481).