# Cannot uninstall MS Teams on ubuntu

Tags: software-uninstall

I recently installed MS Teams on ubuntu 18.04 because I needed it for a project. Now I don't need
it anymore, so I deleted it's .deb file, hoping that doing this would uninstall the app. But
even now, as I turn on my computer, it pops up everytime, which irritates me. I even tried to
uninstall it from ubuntu App Center, but couldn't locate it there. Can anyone suggest me how can I uninstall it?

Thank You!

Comment: Exactly how did you install MS Teams ?

Comment: If you used a `.deb` file, did you perform `dpkg -i /path/to/deb`? If so, [perhaps try the uninstall](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dpkg) command with the `.deb` file.

Answer (score 2):

From a terminal window the process would be the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove <application_name>
```

Typically the <application_name> in this case would be teams

Answer (score 0):

@VIPUL if you are irritated with teams app is because it turns on every time you open up your pc then my suggestion would be that you go to startup applications and disable it if you find it there. Other way would be go to the settings ,then to applications and search for teams and turn off its permission to run in background.
If you want to completely remove it you can try to use the terminal as it can be used to install or uninstall almost every app that you find in software center.
Alternatively you can download synaptics package manager and use it to find the teams app and uninstall it completely from there.

If you face in problem you are free to ask.

This link will guide you on how to install synaptics.
[1]: https://itsfoss.com/synaptic-package-manager/
Or you may refer to this answer:[How can I uninstall software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143/how-can-i-uninstall-software)