# How to uninstall a program in Linux without sudo and root access

Tags: uninstall

I have installed a programme(Dragonfly `ORS`) using `chmod u+x DragonflyInstaller`  `./DragonflyInstaller` in my user home directory `aks@HPGM512GB:~/ORS/Dragonfly$`.

How can I uninstall any program using the terminal without sudo and root access?

To remove the programme, I used `"rm -rf ORS"`, which did remove the installed programme. But I believe it has not completely uninstalled.
I still see the old thumbnail and software behave unexpectedly after reinstall. It shows the `error` `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` which happening(I believe) because the program did not uninstall properly.

Could you please help me with the correct way of uninstalling a programme without admin access?

Thanks

Comment: Related [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143/how-can-i-uninstall-software)

Comment: Which program did you install? Without knowing where all the installer copied the installation files, we really cannot answer the question. Please edit your question and add [this](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1319062/edit) information.

Comment: Why do you believe it has not fully uninstalled? What symptoms/evidence do you see that indicates parts of the program have not been removed?

Comment: Did you remove the program or did you uninstall it? There are totally separate things.

Comment: You ran the script `./programme_installer` and given I've never seen a script of that name, I cannot possibly know (though even if I had seen the script, I'd need to know the actual version etc). I would explore the script itself & see what it does, and work from there.   What that script did, will dictate how to uninstall.

Comment: Eagle_Mike : I want to uninstall, but I could not do using sudo `sudo apt-get --purge remove ORS` as I don't have admin privilege so I thought about removing it `rm -rf ORS`. Could you please let me know how to uninstall without admin privilege, the programme is installed in the current user home directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the programme was installed on the user Home directory, `" rm -rf ORS"` did remove the program files and folder. Problem was due to the additional folder`./ORS`, which was still not removed. I removed the `./ORS` folder, and the issue got resolved.

PS: My question was, "how to uninstall programs without `sudo` privileges", which I assumed should work by removing the programs folder  `rm -rf programme_folder`.