# "Not a directory" error

Tags: command-line, dpkg

Just installed Lubuntu on my laptop. Win8 was the only previous OS on it.

After that I tried install slimjet following this:

https://linuxways.net/ubuntu/how-to-install-slimjet-browser-on-ubuntu-20-04/

But I couldn't since some "not a directory" error happened after CD and dpkg commands didn't work.

This is from my terminal(strangely enough it can recognize 'ls' command and bring the folders, but it won't do the same for typed or even copied paths! )

```
none0@none0-X102BA:~$ cd ~/Downloads/slimjet_amd64.deb
bash: cd: /home/none0/Downloads/slimjet_amd64.deb: Not a directory
none0@none0-X102BA:~$ ~/Downloads$ ls
bash: /home/none0/Downloads$: No such file or directory
none0@none0-X102BA:~$ cd /home/none0/Downloads/slimjet_amd64.deb
bash: cd: /home/none0/Downloads/slimjet_amd64.deb: Not a directory
none0@none0-X102BA:~$
none0@none0-X102BA:~$ ls
Desktop Downloads Music Public Videos
Documents mozilla.pdf Pictures Templates
none0@none0-X102BA:~$ Downloads
Downloads: command not found
none0@none0-X102BA:~$ cd /home/none0/Downloads/slimjet_amd64.deb
bash: cd: /home/none0/Downloads/slimjet_amd64.deb: Not a directory
none0@none0-X102BA:~$ cd /home/none0/Downloads/slimjet_amd64.deb
bash: cd: /home/none0/Downloads/slimjet_amd64.deb: Not a directory
none0@none0-X102BA:~$ sudo dpkg -i slimjet_amd64.deb
[sudo] password for none0:
dpkg: error processing archive slimjet_amd64.deb (--install):
cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
slimjet_amd64.deb
none0@none0-X102BA:~$ rr
The program 'rr' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install rr
```

Comment: Are you new to linux ? You don't know how to run `cd` command

Comment: You may want to first `cd ~/Downloads`, and *then* run `dpkg` ...

Comment: You need to run `cd $HOME && cd Downloads/ && sudo dpkg -i name-of-deb-file.deb`

Comment: @Algnis Bear in mind we don't know what other file may by in the OPs ~/Downloads directory

Comment: I would fault the question here, except that the directions in the link provided are just abysmally wrong.

Comment: @CharlesGreen (1) It is a fresh install (2) I don't  know what is the name of the .deb file (3) som software  works with multiple .deb files (4) OP don't  even know that he/she could not `cd` into a `.deb` file , **anyways I edited it**

Comment: Also **You should never blindly run random commands from web, some commands can break your system, some are only for explanations, Don't  Run a command unless or until you know what it does**

Comment: @user10489 but, but, the author has a degree in telecommunication engineering!

Comment: I don't care how many degrees the author has, the blog instructions are embarrassingly wrong.  Everyone makes mistakes, but that error is so bad I can't think of any excuse for it.

Answer (score 5):

## The instructions on that page is wrong!

The correct commands is:

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

`cd` stands for change directory. `Downloads` is the directory.

Once you complete the above command, you enter the next one:

```
sudo dpkg -i slimjet_amd64.deb
```

You will be asked to enter your password. When you type the password nothing will show on the terminal. This is normal.

## Uninstall

If you don't like the software and want to uninstall it, use the following command:

```
sudo apt remove slimjet
```

Another way to uninstall it is to open the Ubuntu Software Store and search of the slimjet. It should be listed as an installed software, and clicking on the **Remove** button will remove it.

In either case you will need to enter your password.

See [How can I uninstall software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143/how-can-i-uninstall-software) for more on uninstalling software in Ubuntu.

Hope this helps

Comment: Followed your tip and it kinda worked out! Really thanks! Just tell me how do I uninstall it, please.

Comment: *.deb files can be handled with `dpkg` as above, they end up in the "installed software" database of `apt` which is the command line tool for install / uninstall -ing SW. `sudo apt purge packagename` will remove all files related to that package.

Comment: @Mrvl Please accept the answer as correct by clicking on the gray check mark ✔️ and turn it green ✅. This will help others. To uninstall the app, use `sudo apt remove slimjet` or open the Ubuntu App Store app and search for it and click remove.

Answer (score 0):

You can't cd (change directory) to the .deb file as it's not a directory.
Try executing `sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/slimjet_amd64.deb` in order to install slimjet_amd64.deb located inside Downloads directory.